# How to automatically set scrollview to go top of the page when I press next

Tags: javascript, c#, android, css, scrollview

"Text here "

"the long Texts that scrolls all the way down"

"At the end there is a next button"

"but when I click next the scrollview stays down"

"how can I make it do back up automatically"

Answer (score 0):

When you click `nextButton` just do this

`yourScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);`

and with this code you scroll your `scrollView` back to up possition.

Comment: thanks a lot and this is to be added on oncreate right?

Comment: is it works? Add this code in your OnCLickListener of your button